# android why my service run() not working

Tags: android, android-service

I have an Android service which I start using an Intent from a class:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), MyService.class);
i.putExtra("Arrived_To_Destination","yes");
getActivity().startService(i);
```

MyService code:

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    String arrival_event;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d("hi","Inside3");
        arrival_event = intent.getStringExtra("Arrived_To_Destination");
        Log.d("hi","Inside0" + arrival_event);
        WorkerThread dialogthread = new WorkerThread(arrival_event);
        Log.d("hi","Inside1");
        dialogthread.start();
        Log.d("hi","Inside2");
        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }

    private class WorkerThread extends Thread {
        String arrival_event;

        public WorkerThread(String arrival_event) {
        this.arrival_event = arrival_event;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.d("hi","Inside4" + arrival_event);
            try {
                Log.d("hi","Inside5" + arrival_event);
                if(arrival_event.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
                    Log.d("hi","Inside6");
                    MyFragment mf = new MyFragment();
                    Log.d("hi","Inside7");
                    mf.showDialog();
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error("Error: ", e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Once the service is started, I get the logs -

```
Inside 0 
Inside 1
Inside 2
Inside 3
Inside 4
```

MyClass

```
private void updateLocation(Child currentchild, Location location) {
if (distancetodestination <= 100) {
                    // the destination reached; 100 is the 100metres, so if the child is within 100m, the arrival event is sent
                    logger.info("Child arrived");

                    isAtDesination = true;
                    child_arrived = true;
                    MyApi.sendArrival(child);

                   }
                }
}
```

The problem is I am not getting inside the `if` statement. In `MyClass`, I have declared `child_arrived` as `public static boolean child_arrived;`

Once the child arrives, I set the value to true. Why `MyService` is not executing the `if` statement.

Comment: The problem should be in your `MyClass`. You aren't doing anything to it here.

Comment: when this `MyClass.child_arrived` flag changed?

Comment: @Sufian I just check the value of it as true in my service. And in MyClass, when an event occurs(child arrives), I set the value of boolean to true

Comment: @Mark023 show the piece of code where you're setting it. Something must be wrong there.

Comment: @Sufian MyClass is a location class which keeps recording the distance of a child to destination. Once destination reached, it fires arrival event. That Time, I set it to true.

Comment: @Sufian Please see my edited question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is both code in separate `threads` thats why can not communicate this way you can pass then flag along with intent while launching service or save flag values in `shared preferences` and then check here.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
intent.putExtra("Flag","0")
startService(intent);
```

**MyService.java**

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    int flag;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d("hi","Inside0");

        flag = intent.getStringextra("Flag");

        WorkerThread dialogthread = new WorkerThread(flag);
        Log.d("hi","Inside1");
        dialogthread.start();
        Log.d("hi","Inside2");
        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }
 private class WorkerThread extends Thread {

        int flag;

        public WorkerThread(int flag) {
              this.flag = flag;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.d("hi","Inside3");
            try {
                Log.d("hi","Inside4");
                if(flag  == 0) {
                    Log.d("hi","Inside5");
                    MyFragment mf = new MyFragment();
                    Log.d("hi","Inside6");
                    mf.showDialog();
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error("Error : ", e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank yu :) I will try this and let you know :)

Comment: @Mark023 can you update your question with the latest code?

Comment: @Mark023 how you are starting you service before there is something we are missing?

Comment: @SohailZahid I have a Fragment class that receives arrival event in a broadcast receiver. Inside that, I am starting this service

Comment: @Mark023 it seems that you got it working, but how? What changes did you make?

Comment: @Sufian Your code is working for me. The mistake I was doing was I was starting the service from a wrong class

Comment: @Mark023 I see. It wasn't my answer though. :)